# How To: get webservice response by directly typing webservice url in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

At the moment I am running through a problem, I am not able to directly invoke the webservice method by directly pasting the entire webservice url along with the method name in the browser address bar.

Where as if browse the webservice ".asmx" first and click on "Invoke" Button like in "Webservice_1" image I have attached along for the particular webservice method the click in from the webservice list that is displayed while I browse the webservice ".asmx" page, the response get displayed like in "webservice_2" image.

But if try to copy and paste the url from "webservice_2" image and paste it in browser address bar, web request ends with error "Request format is unrecognized for URL unexpectedly ending in '/GetEmployeeLogins'." as in image "webservice_3"

I think it should be possible to directly call webservice methods by simply pasting the url .Hope you guys would correct me if I am wrong.

Please suggest me if I can make some correction to make webservice method accessible by copy pasting the full url in the browser. An quick help would be really appreciable!

Comment: this link may help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/45fez2a8(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This findings could be really hopeful for the rest of those which may have faced similar problem. The "request format error" occur basically because the url request generally exhibits GET action is to be enabled in "web.config" with following tag element:

```
<System.Web>
<webServices>
      <protocols>
        <add name="HttpGet"/>
        <add name="HttpPost"/>
        <add name="HttpSoap"/>
      </protocols>
</webServices>
</System.Web>
```

This helped me very well and i hope the very best for others too.Please mark the answer if it truely helped you. Thanks.

Comment: Good on you for returning with a solution